# Haproxy configuration binding an interface

Tags: haproxy

I have a setup question for my future configuration. 
I have a vm jessie with 2 networks interfaces (eth0 and eth1)  and i want to tell to my haproxy configuration to bind trafic from eth1. 
Is someone can help ?

Answer (score 6):

Just use bind directive:

```
bind [<address>]:<port_range> [, ...] interface <interface>
```

Comes from the manual: http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.3/doc/configuration.txt

Update: It's the same for newer versions - check out:

http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/doc/configuration.txt > 5.1. Bind options > interface < interface >

> Restricts the socket to a specific interface. When specified, only
>   packets   received from that particular interface are processed by the
>   socket. This is   currently only supported on Linux. The interface
>   must be a primary system   interface, not an aliased interface. It is
>   also possible to bind multiple   frontends to the same address if they
>   are bound to different interfaces. Note   that binding to a network
>   interface requires root privileges. This parameter   is only
>   compatible with TCPv4/TCPv6 sockets.

Comment: I forgot to tell that i'm using version1.5.8. In the manual it's not defined or maybe rewrited

Comment: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.5/configuration.html#4-bind